# Is the code samples same about copying initial in C++?

Tags: c++

```
struct Foo {
  int value; 
  Foo(int v):value(v) {};  
  };

Foo foo=10;
```

code sample one:

```
Foo foo2=foo;
```

code sample two:

```
Foo foo3(foo);
```

is the sample code two equal with the sample code one?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the sample code two equal with the sample code one?

Yes, the two objects `foo2` and `foo3` will contain the same `value` as `foo`. You [can see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d7a5792675ecbf9) that the `value` member variable of both is the same.

As [Johan Lundberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1149664/johan-lundberg) made notice, `Foo foo2 = foo;` only works if the constructor is not declared `explicit` (like in your case).

> Do them both call copy constructor?

In this case yes they both call the copy constructor. Notice that if:

```
Foo foo2 = foo;
```

was:

```
Foo foo2(0);
foo2 = foo;
```

there would be a call at the `Foo(int)` constructor and then a call to the `operator=` function instead.

Comment: As long as the constructor is not explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The two statements are not equivalent: `foo2` is conceptually initialized by a copy of `foo` while `foo3` copies `foo` directly. In your code you can't see the difference but if you make `Foo`'s copy constructor `explicit`, the initialization of `foo2` does not work while the initialization of `foo3` does work.